# node does not have storage.objects.create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

permission error for uploading images to google cloud storage, but I already gave proper permissions on IAM

```
Error: reportai-images@even-shuttle-250512.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to reportai-images/images.jpeg.
    at Gaxios.request (/home/jvcabral/Projects/reportai_image_upload/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

[IAM Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQuyi.png)

Comment: did you search for that error already to see what possible solutions might be? For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120745/node-does-not-have-storage-objects-create may be for python, but the solution is unrelated to the programming language, because it's a gservice error.

Comment: all the solutions I found said to give permission to the IAM account, but I already did it and the error continues

Answer (score 0):

The IAM member account does not have the permission `storage.objects.create` on your project.

To list the IAM member roles assigned to a project execute this command. Replace PROJECT_ID with your Project ID which appears to be `even-shuttle-250512`.

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID > project_roles.txt
```

Review the file `project_roles.txt` for the member and confirm what roles are assigned to the service account:

```
reportai-images@even-shuttle-250512.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

To add a role to the project granting the service account the required permission:

Windows Syntax:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID ^
--member=serviceAccount:reportai-images@even-shuttle-250512.iam.gserviceaccount.com ^
--role=roles/storage.admin
```

Linux/macOS Syntax:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \
--member=serviceAccount:reportai-images@even-shuttle-250512.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/storage.admin
```

Note that in the previous command I assigned the role Storage Admin. Pick a role that meets your requirements for least privilege. For example `roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter` is probably more appropriate.

[Cloud IAM roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)